# Array of objects not working correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, object, linked-list

I have an class that creates an array of objects from another class(the array class is friend)

```
class vector_XXL
{
        int i=0,n=0; 
        XXL_nr *XXLvector;

public:
    vector_XXL(int y)
    {
        n = y;
      XXLvector = new XXL_nr[y];}
```

n is the size of the array. XXL_nr is class that creates large numbers represented as a linked list(each digit has a spot on the list)

I want the product of each 2 numbers from 2 array objects on the same positions. So, for example, v[i]*d[i] , for i = 0,n;

This is the function that should do that but it doesn't work correctly:

```
void produs_scalar(vector_XXL A)
{
    XXL_nr temp(2),temp1(2),temp2(2),result(2);
    vector_XXL vector_result(n);

    temp1 = this->XXLvector[0];
    temp2 = A.XXLvector[0];
    temp1.addition(temp2);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   temp = this->XXLvector[i].product(A.XXLvector[i]);
        vector_result.XXLvector[i] = temp;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        result= temp.product(vector_result.XXLvector[i]);

    result.print();

}
```

I used temp1, and temp2 to test if I can use the product method(defined in class XXL_nr) on 2 XXL_nr variables. But the result is the same. Problem is, in the first for loop, it does the product, it returns the correct answer for `this->XXLvector[i].product(A.XXLvector[i]); but it does not move to the i-th position, the entire program just hangs there after the product method returns.
Now, I believe the array is the problem, because I tried doing the product without using an array(just XXL_nr types) and the method doesn't hang anymore. Example:

```
void produs_scalar()//vector_XXL &A)
{
    XXL_nr B(2), C(2), D;
    cout<<"insert number B";
    cin>> B;
    cout<<"number C";
    cin>>C;
    D=B.product(C);
    cout<<D;
```

Here, everything works just fine. the product methos returns, and the code adcances to `cout<<D;` .

I read on one topic that when the program hangs like this it's because of something pointing to random memory and the program just hangs, but I have no idea how to debug that or how to verify if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment to 'temp' from the product is incorrect.  In the array demonstration you assign the result of 'product' to type XXL_nr(2) while in your example with no arrays you are assigning the result to type XXL_nr.  Without code for the XXL_nr I am unclear as to the type that is being created.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. You are right... without the XXL_nr class there isn't much that anyone can deduce, but I have like 1k lines of code only on that class and I don't think adding it is gonna help. Thanks though, I'll see what I can do... I'ts weird because I can cout, cin , iterate through the loop but I just can't for the life of me make it return the result from product, even though product does everything correctly, I printed the result to the console before it reached the return statement. I just can't understand why it doesn't return...